# InfoPath Postback Infinite Loop

Tags: 2013, infopath, forms-services, postback

I'm working on an InfoPath form and came across a weird error. Whenever I go to the edit form and change any text box (rules or not), the console appears to send postbacks forever until it hits the server limit. I've tried upping that limit in Central Admin to 200 and it kept sending requests until it hit that new limit. I've tried clearing cookies (which has resolved issues before) and multiple browsers/machines. No luck. Has anyone experienced this issue before and found a fix for it? It's a fairly large and complex form so I'd rather not have to start over with it or delete random fields until it works.

Error in dialog

`This session has exceeded the amount of allowable resources.
Click Start over to load a new copy of the form. If this error persists, contact the support team for the Web site.
Click Close to exit this message.`

Exception from correlation ID

`Number of postbacks, 203, has exceeded 200, the maximum allowable value per session. This value is configurable and can be changed by the administrator. (User: 0#.w|[DOMAIN]\[USER], Form Name: [FORM NAME], IP: , Request: [URL], Form ID: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:list:-AutoGen-2018-06-20T17:17:37:402Z)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue. To do this I added a seemingly random field to the bottom of the form and hid it. Magically, the issue went away. Others can feel free to submit a better answer about why that happened but to anyone else experiencing this and coming here from Google:

Try adding in random duplicate fields and it just might start working.